# Similar function Arduino bitWrite

Tags: arduino

For a raspberry pi project, I am trying to change arduino code.
Does anybody know a similar function of this?

http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/BitWrite#.U143R1eehRU

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, i think i could do it on my own :)

```
void bitWrite(uint8_t &x, unsigned int n, bool b) {
    if (n <= 7 && n >= 0) {
        if (b) {
            x |= (1u << n);
        } else {
            x &= ~(1u << n);
        }
    }    
}
```